# Python3 MySQL SSL Error - mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, ssl

I have spent all day on this and cant figure it out. I have no problems connecting to the remote server using python and the mysql.connector but when i try using SSL I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 384, in switch_to_ssl
         self.sock.do_handshake()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 804, in do_handshake
         self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:600)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./mysql_test.py", line 25, in <module>
         con = mysql.connector.connect(**config);
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
         return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
         self.connect(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 719, in connect
         self._open_connection()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 210, in _open_connection
         self._ssl)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 134, in _do_auth
         self._socket.switch_to_ssl(**ssl_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 390, in switch_to_ssl
         errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
    mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '192.168.1.10:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:600)
```

- system spec both servers:
- Debian 8.2
- OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
- mysql 5.7.X.
- python3
- pip3
- mysql.connector = Connector/Python 2.1.3

I know the ssl connection works with php and cli mysql connections but i can't figure out how to get ssl to work properly. I have also tried to change the ssl protocol in the mysql.connector network.py source. I have also tried with and without use_pure flag. Any help is greatly appreciated.

the python source:

```
    import mysql.connector
     config = {
        'user' : 'uname', 
        'password' :'passwd', 
        'host' : '192.168.1.10',
        'database' : 'python',
        'ssl_ca' : '/etc/mysql/ssl/client/ca-cert.pem',
        'ssl_cert' : '/etc/mysql/ssl/client/client-cert.pem',
        'ssl_key' : '/etc/mysql/ssl/client/client-key.pem',
        'use_pure' : 'False'
    }
    con = mysql.connector.connect(**config);
    con.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Needed to remove the ssl_key and ssl_cert connection arguments, and only supply the ssl_ca and it works like a charm.